# how to translate stata into R

Tags: r, variables, stata

I need to make a dataset for a set of years and per year a certain function will calculate the values. I have the program in STATA but am having difficulties to translate it into R. The years are from 2017 to 2025 and a value of 17305004 for the year 2017. From then on the total hours increase with 0.025 per year at a fixed hourprice.

Here is the program in STATA:

```
set obs 9

scalar growth=.025

scalar hourprice=32

egen year = seq(), from(2017) to(2025) 

gen totalhours = .

replace totalhours=17305004 if year==2017

replace totalhours=[(totalhours[_n-1] + growth*totalhours[_n-1])] if year!=2017

format  %10.0g  totalhours

gen cost = .

replace cost=totalhours*hourprice

format  %12.0g  cost

list year totalhours cost
```

Comment: please show some reproducible example, your attempts, and your desired output

Comment: SO is not a translating service. Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
year <- 2017:2025
totalhours <- c(17305004, rep(NA, 8))
for(i in 1:8){
  totalhours[i+1] <- totalhours[i] + totalhours[i]*.025
}
cost <- totalhours*32

mydata <- data.frame(year, totalhours, cost)
```

Dataset:

```
> mydata
  year totalhours      cost
1 2017   17305004 553760128
2 2018   17737629 567604131
3 2019   18181070 581794234
4 2020   18635597 596339090
5 2021   19101486 611247568
6 2022   19579024 626528757
7 2023   20068499 642191976
8 2024   20570212 658246775
9 2025   21084467 674702944
```

`totalhours` could probably be generated easier, I just couldn't come up with a better way right now.

Comment: thank you so much! this matches perfect with the STATA output!

Comment: You are welcome. If your request is completely fulfilled, you might want to check the "Accept answer" box.